# Flutter Role-based Authentication

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, role-base-authorization, role-based-access-control

[My Firbase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iSKSo.png)
I'm developing an app with flutter. The app should use different pages for different kinds of users. There are 4 kinds of user: "Admin", "Staff", "Member", "Collector". The problem is, that I'm not able to get to the different pages and always stay on what role I put. I'm new on this flutter and dart so I need someone to help me for my capstone project. Thank you!

Here's my code for main.dart

```
class MainPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const MainPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);


   Future<String> getRole(String uid) async {
    String role = "admin";

    try {
      final snapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('users')
          .doc(uid)
          .get();
      if (snapshot.exists) {
        role = snapshot.get('role').toString();
      } else {
        print('Document does not exist in the database');
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
    return role;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: StreamBuilder<User?>(
        stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return const Center(child: Text('Something Went Wrong!'));
          } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
            // User is authenticated, check their role
            final users = snapshot.data!;
            return FutureBuilder<String>(
              future: getRole(users.uid),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                  return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                  return const Center(child: Text('Something Went Wrong!'));
                } else {
                  final String? role = snapshot.data;
                  if (role == "admin") {
                    return const AdminPage();
                  } else if (role == "staff") {
                    return const StaffPage();
                  } else if (role == "member") {
                    return const MemberPage();
                  } else if (role == "collector") {
                    return const CollectorPage();
                  } else {
                    // Unknown role, handle accordingly
                    return const SigninPage();
                  }
                }
              },
            );
          } else {
            // User is not authenticated, show sign-in page
            return const SigninPage();
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }

}
```

Here's my code for signInPage:

```
Future signIn() async{
     showDialog(
    context: context,
    barrierDismissible: false,
    builder: (context) => const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
  );

    try {
    await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
      email: emailController.text.trim(),
      password: passwordController.text.trim(),
    );
  } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
    print(e);
    Utils.showSnackBar(e.message);
  }

  Navigator.of(context).popUntil((route) => route.isFirst);
}
```

Here's my code for signUpPage:

```
Future signUp() async{
  final isValid = formKey.currentState!.validate();
  if (!isValid) return;


    showDialog(
    context: context,
    barrierDismissible: false, 
    builder: (context) => const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()));

    try{
    await FirebaseAuth.instance.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
      email: emailController.text.trim(),
      password: passwordController.text.trim(),
    );

    //Display User to FireStore
    addUserDetailes(
      firstnameController.text.trim(),
      middlenameController.text.trim(),
      lastnameController.text.trim(),
      fulladdressController.text.trim(),
      civilstatuscontroller.text.trim(),
      emailController.text.trim(),
      int.parse(phonenoController.text.trim()),
      int.parse(ageController.text.trim()),
      );
    }on FirebaseAuthException catch (e){
      print(e);

      Utils.showSnackBar(e.message);
    }

    //Navigator.of(context) not working! 
    navigatorKey.currentState!.popUntil((route) =>route.isFirst);
  }

//display to database
Future addUserDetailes(String firstName, String middleName, String lastName, String fullAddress, String civilStatus, String email, int phoneNumber, int age ) async{
  await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').add({
    'first name': firstName,
    'middle name': middleName,
    'last name': lastName,
    'full address': fullAddress,
    'civil status' : civilStatus,
    'email': email,
    'phone number': phoneNumber,
    'age' : age,
    
  });
}
```

If you need more information about my code you can comment here. I really need help, Thank you very much!!!

Comment: You need to load users profiles to know who is what then you can display page of not according user role information loaded. 

Ex. from build method :

if(role == and)
return Widget1
else{
return WidgetUnauthorizedPage
}

Comment: can you please more elaborate?

Comment: do you have an API or backend ?

If yes, than after successfull authentification then load role information according connected user and use that for check page access

Comment: No, I don't have

Comment: So how do you know roles'user in your system ?

Comment: I'm just watching tutorial on YouTube. The only backend in my code is that when you signup it will save to firebase.

Comment: Ok, you need to have system that indicate and save user's role somewhere

Comment: I already have firebase saving the user information but not the user role. I manually add roles to the user in firestore.

Comment: I already add my firebase photo here